# Running “kubectl proxy” for a single request

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any way to run `kubectl proxy`, giving it a command as input, and shutting it down when the response is received?

I'm imagining something with the `-u` (unix socket) flag, like this:

```
kubectl proxy -u - < $(echo "GET /api/v1/namespaces/default")
```

I don't think it's possible, but maybe my socket fu just isn't strong enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kubectl proxy` won't give you any way to run a one-off request and terminate the proxy.

Generic way to start a command in the background, run a command and terminate the initially started command finally would be to write a bash script like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

kubectl proxy &
proxy_pid=$!
echo $proxy_pid

until curl -fsSL http://localhost:8001/ > /dev/null; do
    echo "waiting for kubectl proxy" >&2
    sleep 5
    # TODO add max retries so you can break out of this
done

curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default

function cleanup {
    echo "killing kubectl proxy" >&2
    kill $proxy_pid
}
trap cleanup EXIT
```

If you actually want to use sockets:

- Start the unix domain socket like `kubectl proxy -u ./foo.sock`
- Make sure your cURL supports unix domain sockets and call `curl --unix-socket ./foo.sock http:/api/v1/namespaces/default` etc.

Comment: That script (minus the "waiting for kubectl proxy" step) is exactly what I'm doing. Accepting the answer because I think you're right, there isn't a way.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a long-running `kubectl proxy` for this.

Try this:

```
kubectl get --raw=/api/v1/namespaces/default
```

Comment: I have use cases that require proxy. I'm not really trying to `get ns`. Just using that example for simplicity.

Comment: If you're doing `GET` requests, this command will work for all those operations.

Comment: I'm not doing GET requests

Comment: It would be better if you can clarify that in your question to begin with, then. Because this answer technically is a valid answer to the example your question (as it is right now), but clearly you're asking for more.

Comment: I think you might have skipped over the question in the first paragraph :) The example is admittedly oversimplified, but I think it's clear given this comment thread?

Comment: you can use this to quickly retrieve the openid-configuration `kubectl get --raw=/.well-known/openid-configuration`